# NullPointerException when referencing DataFrame column names with $ method call

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Following is a simple word count Spark App using DataFrame and the corresponding unit tests using spark-testingbase. It works if I use the following

```
def toWords(linesDf: DataFrame) = {
        linesDf
          .select(linesDf("line"),
            explode(split(linesDf("line"), WhitespaceRegex)).as("word"))
}
```

But doesn't work if I use `$` method call to reference the columns as shown below

```
def toWords(linesDf: DataFrame) = {
    import spark.implicits._
    linesDf
        .select($"line"),
            explode(split($"line", WhitespaceRegex)).as("word"))
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.aravind.oss.eg.wordcount.spark.WordCountDFApp$.toWords(WordCountDFApp.scala:42)
    at com.aravind.oss.eg.wordcount.spark.WordCountDFAppTestSpec2$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(WordCountDFAppTestSpec2.scala:32)
    at com.aravind.oss.eg.wordcount.spark.WordCountDFAppTestSpec2$$anonfun$1.apply(WordCountDFAppTestSpec2.scala:17)
    at com.aravind.oss.eg.wordcount.spark.WordCountDFAppTestSpec2$$anonfun$1.apply(WordCountDFAppTestSpec2.scala:17)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
```

**Spark App**

```
object WordCountDFApp extends App with Logging {
  logInfo("WordCount with Dataframe API")

  val paths = getPaths(args)
  val cluster = getClusterCfg(args)

  if (paths.size > 1) {
    logInfo("More than one file to process")
  }
  logInfo("Path(s): " + paths)
  logInfo("Cluster: " + cluster)

  val spark = getSparkSession("WordCountDFApp", cluster)

  val linesDf: DataFrame = spark.read
    .textFile(paths: _*)
    .toDF("line") //Dataset[Row]
  logInfo("DataFrame before splitting line")
  linesDf.show(false)

  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val wordsDf = toWords(linesDf)

  logInfo("Inferred schema")
  wordsDf.printSchema()

  logInfo("DataFrame after splitting the line into words")
  wordsDf.show(false)

  countWords(wordsDf).show(false)

  def toWords(linesDf: DataFrame) = {
    linesDf
      .select(linesDf("line"),
        explode(split(linesDf("line"), WhitespaceRegex)).as("word"))
  }

}
```

**Test**

```
class WordCountDFAppTestSpec2 extends FlatSpec with DataFrameSuiteBase {

  val input: Seq[String] = Seq(
    ("one"),
    ("two"),
    (""),
    ("three Three")
  )

  "toWords" should "split the file into words" in {
    val sqlCtx = sqlContext
    import sqlCtx.implicits._
    val sourceDf = input.toDF("line")
    // sourceDf.show(false)

    val expectedDF = Seq(
      ("one", "one"),
      ("two", "two"),
      ("", ""),
      ("three Three", "three"),
      ("three Three", "Three")
    ).toDF("line", "word")
    // expectedDF.show(false)

    val actualDF = WordCountDFApp.toWords(sourceDf)
    // actualDF.show(false)

    assertDataFrameEquals(actualDF, expectedDF)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the implicits is not imported in runtime, you need to add this line:

```
import linesDf.sparkSession.implicits._
```

in your method, e.g:

```
  def toWords(linesDf: DataFrame) = {
import linesDf.sparkSession.implicits._
linesDf
  .select($"line",
    explode(split(linesDf("line"), WhitespaceRegex)).as("word"))
```

}

and that will fix the problem.

Comment: This fixes the issue. But why this has to be imported during runtime when the code compiles and I've the following import already in the codebase: import spark.implicits._
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

Comment: Yes, but calling "import spark.implicits._" in WordCountDFAppTestSpec.scala is only bring the implicits to this module, also you call import in WordCountDFApp, but it is never been calling in the test because you call to WordCountDFApp.toWords(), and that not submit the code in the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

You should call/import `sqlContext.implicits` to access `$`(dollar sign) in your code

```
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
```

So your full imports looks like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Comment: What is the number of line column?

Comment: it is the first and the only column.

Comment: can you try this one `linesDf.select($"_c0").show()`

Comment: It doesn't work. Also, wanted to share that the code I've posted doesn't work only when run from unit test.

Comment: can you share working version of your code on to open repo so that we test and help you if you wish

Comment: Appreciate the help. Here is the full working code on GitHub. It is a full maven project so all you need to do is run "mvn test". https://github.com/yaravind/learn-spark/tree/master/stackoverflow-complete. You need to clone https://github.com/yaravind/learn-spark and then "cd stackoverflow-complete".

Comment: Run this test: https://github.com/yaravind/learn-spark/blob/master/stackoverflow-complete/src/test/scala/com/aravind/oss/eg/wordcount/spark/WordCountDFAppTestSpec.scala

Comment: @AravindYarram, opened an issue to discuss: https://github.com/yaravind/learn-spark/issues/1